# Finding a loop invariant - Hoare Triple

Tags: while-loop, logic, predicates, loop-invariant, hoare-logic

From the following code, I need to deduce/choose a loop invariant.

```
(|true|)
x = 0 ;
s = 0 ;
while ( x <= n ) {
    s = s + x ;
    x = x + 1 ;
}
(|s = n(n + 1)/2|)
```

Solution given was

- s = (x-1)*x/2 ∧ (x ≤ n +1)

I don't quite understand how it has reached the solution above.

Please, help me with how to derive such solution or other loop invariant from the code.

Comment: there seem to be multiple typos. The last `1)=2` should be `1)/2`, and in your formula for the invariant, I would expect it to start `s = (x+1)` instead of `0 = (x-1)`. Can you confirm and edit?

Comment: Hello @tucuxi Thanks for pointing those errors out. Yeah, I edited those. In my pdf file, it says 0 = (x-1), but it doesn't make sense. it should be s, I agree with you.

Comment: understood. I fixed it :) @tucuxi

Comment: But right before the loop terminates, x+=1; and it is going to be x = n+1. Then n = x-1. when substituting n with x term, shouldn't it be (x-1)*x/2 ? @tucuxi

Comment: Oops. Apparently I got ahead of myself. `x-1` was ok (when ending the loop, x-1 works out to n; so x). Sorry for adding confusion.

Comment: okay. thank you @tucuxi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the invariant, you can easily check that it is true before, within, and after the loop (yes, adding up integers from 1 to n inclusive gives you (n+1)*n/2 - see [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) ). Since it covers all relevant variables in the loop (`x` and `s`), and cannot be further refined (well, you *could* add `^ x >= 0`), it is indeed *the* invariant.

To deduce it by yourself, I am afraid that you need to know about triangular numbers (or the half-the-square) formula beforehand. You can of course write out that `s = sum of integers from 1 to x` for that part, and I for one would take it as a valid invariant. The part where `x <= n+1` is comparatively easy.

A layman's way of finding invariants is to try to write out what the variables of the loop do during their lifetime inside the loop:

- s always holds the sum of integers up to x
- x goes through the integers from 0 to n, inclusive

And then writing it out in math.

Comment: wow, thank you for fast feedback and answer. I understood now that why this invariant is chosen.